# How to make g++ use the C++20 language standard when compiling from code-blocks in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, compiling, c++, g++, code-blocks

Just started learning c++ and it is recommended to compile code using the c++20 standard and use code::blocks as the editor.

I checked the man pages of g++ and it is using c++17. I am using code::blocks IDE on Ubuntu 22.04.  There is no option in the code::blocks compiler settings for c++20.

How do I update g++ so the option for compiling with c++20 is available in code::blocks.

Comment: I don't know about code::blocks, but if you want to use GUI, this can be configured in VS Code using the compiler argument `-std=c++20`. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `g++ -std=c++20 filename.cpp`

Comment: I am trying to make the option appear in code-blocks so I can compile with that standard from the toolbar